# GridLines getting removed on y-axis visibility off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

I was making visibility false for y-axis as I don't wanna show y-axis hence made visible false but the problem here is gridlines also got removed which needs to be kept in the chart. How to make y-axis visibility off by keeping the gridlines?

Please find the working demo here => **[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/4hc3ekty/)** Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code part:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Subhojit'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Height (cm)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        },
        visible: false
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: <data>
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which I was looking for and thought of sharing with you all if it be of any help to anyone someday.

Please find the working solution here => **[JSFiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/k850ah1t/)**

Below is the solution of hiding the axis line and labels without effecting the gridlines:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Weight (kg)'
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    lineColor: 'transparent'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.enabled?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=2bc5bcf661639b8a9140966080b0654b0bbdb614-1620913974-0-AT4axGbg_HivND3RDAb_Qh45bxJPZCtLufCwqBZEs1A7uXwzSSulO8PHB5Mb9qfGJDiRHLMZArxofc_IyqrU7_qF9YxFWp-4_I0UjWZGIqsktbM9BczuqA_Ec_WgBlaJ-H_Zkcp2ZKCMR2EoLjvCD0PHT0EHNLQr48Dbpg9Hkn9UlkJkpeW_JhErL12Wphxv5IF6N9-DZcZ08SEQSKLhJZM_IhiLjLoNG-AoBntTb7izLOGrk03i10wMGdY7F-d0NT9YXQnqnDeMfYo1K0tPVpcIfRZ4z9MN9px5Y4XrQevd_pw92b_wR97oWlJQZ7xt2B8Z6Y719jdDC7WTf-vkt0mCPxcxJEWnQl5VtniGIS0Xq8WLQnBjU6dnpmzBX5b2Rg0BBDBunHE-G1pYEw6Y312Lt_3gXd5f8cL3m-tOXfrQQEgsbFQiNtPW7q7cpNmhwt57DPdrdeP2Lf5UkfmfiGWyKpr_lkub0I-Oj1ZVLTzWn57byvgjRDvAtkoNFgrpJXV27LGcz4LNy-yxVnDp461WoCHkYNuVobtufJAD_jXRZlkqM8B9hoNXrb-kocZDmKXzf3NLvzZsuajUgFcD8Zn--IIPuNXFN6J3uD71fJj3yRWvAWo12cCoxeNkcA1fSAaStUzvinShf25eZg3oknQK6it4BA1_ndDoGp4zRwXX) To hide labels we need to `labels` object and in that object need to pass `enabled: false`

```
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
```

Highcharts [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-enabled/)

Comment: That's fine but it only hides the axis labels not the axis line

Comment: Sorry, i was busy with other stuff so did not get chance to look at your comment. I saw your answer. I did not thought to set lineColor. Great work!